# Get channel for bluetooth transfer without sdptool

Tags: linux, bluetooth, arch-linux

According to [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth#Shell_command_is_missing_from_bluez-utils), `sdptool` is removed from `bluez-utils`.

So how can I see does a device support Obex Object Push and (if it does) a channel for transfer, without it (I need a new way to do what the first command [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth#Obex_Object_Push) does using `sdptool`).

I'd rather not install [bluez-utils-compat](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/bluez-utils-compat/) (it removes new `bluez-utils`, plus **PGP keys** of this package can't be verified).

I'm on Arch Linux (if it's not obvious from links in this question), `bluez-utils` version is 5.49 and I can succesfully connect to all (well, to all of those that I tried to connect to) bluetooth devices using `bluetoothctl`.